# Explode an Entity Object in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

I'm trying to create galleries in my Symfony2 Web App.

Each post may or may not have a gallery. My galleries are text mapping types, under the Post entity/class:

```
#Post.orm.yml

MyProject\MyProjectBundle\Entity\Post:
type: entity
table: post
repositoryClass: MyProject\MyProjectBundle\Entity\PostRepository
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator: { strategy: AUTO }
    fields:
        # ...
        gallery:
            type: text
            nullable: true
        #...
```

As there are many images in a gallery, I figured it would have made sense to separate each image with a comma via my data fixture:

```
image1.png, image2.jpg, examplename-3rdimage.gif, 4thandfinal.jpg
```

However, I want the gallery to be output like this when it's viewed:

```
<li>image1.png</li>
<li>image2.jpg</li>
<li>examplename-3rdimage.gif</li>
<li>4thandfinal.jpg</li>
```

My controller then calls for the Post Entity:

```
/* PostController.php */

public function postshowAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('MPMPBBundle:Post')->find($id);

    $gallery = $em->getRepository('MPMPBBundle:Post')->getGallery();


    if (!$entities) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
    }

    return $this->render('MPMPBBundle:Post:postshow.html.twig', array(
        'entities'      => $entities,
        'gallery'       => $gallery
    ));
}
```

As you may have noticed, I reference the function: `getGallery()` from my repository class: `PostRepository`:

```
/* PostRepository.php */

class PostRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getGallery()
    {
        $postGallery = $this->createQueryBuilder('e')
                            ->select('e.gallery')
                            ->getQuery()
                            ->getResult();

        $gallery = array();
        foreach ($postGallery as $postGal)
        {
            $gallery = array_merge(explode(",", $postGal['gallery']), $gallery);
        }

        foreach ($gallery as &$gal)
        {
            $gal = trim($gal);
        }

        return $gallery;
    }
}
```

Finally, my twig file: `postshow.html.twig`, looks like this:

```
{% for gallery in gallery %}
    <li>{{ gallery }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

**To clarify, what I am looking to achieve is this:**

```
# mysite.com/post/post-1

<li>image1.png</li>
<li>image2.jpg</li>
<li>examplename-3rdimage.gif</li>
<li>4thandfinal.jpg</li>

# mysite.com/post/post-2

<li>image5.png</li>
<li>image11.jpg</li>
<li>examplename-18thimage.gif</li>
<li>22ndandfinal.jpg</li>
```

**Each post displays it's respective gallery.**

With what's written above, what is achieved is that ALL the `Gallery` items from every `Post` is output, whereas I only need the gallery item for individual posts:

```
# mysite.com/post/post-1

<li>image1.png</li>
<li>image2.jpg</li>
<li>examplename-3rdimage.gif</li>
<li>4thandfinal.jpg</li>
<li>image5.png</li>
<li>image11.jpg</li>
<li>examplename-18thimage.gif</li>
<li>22ndandfinal.jpg</li>

# mysite.com/post/post-2

<li>image1.png</li>
<li>image2.jpg</li>
<li>examplename-3rdimage.gif</li>
<li>4thandfinal.jpg</li>
<li>image5.png</li>
<li>image11.jpg</li>
<li>examplename-18thimage.gif</li>
<li>22ndandfinal.jpg</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gallery` field is in the `Post` table, so you dont need to query again in the db, just get the `gallery` from the current entitie and `explode()` it like this:

```
/* PostController.php */

public function postshowAction($id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $entities = $em->getRepository('MPMPBBundle:Post')->find($id);

    $gallery = null;
    if (null !== $entities->getGallery())
    {
        $gallery = explode(",", $entities->getGallery());
        $gallery = array_map("trim", $gallery);
    }

    if (!$entities) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Post entity.');
    }

    return $this->render('MPMPBBundle:Post:postshow.html.twig', array(
        'entities'      => $entities,
        'gallery'       => $gallery
    ));
}
```

Comment: I'm so... I'm so damn slow. I was sure it was something obvious, but I didn't think it was that obvious. Thanks a lot. I appreciate it.